# PHP DOMDocument, remove element by Id

Tags: php, domdocument

Been trying now for almost an hour. And though everyone insists in how easy and straight forward it is handling XML/HTML with DOMDocument I don't find a proper answer.

How do I remove element id=delete_me completely from this simple html?

```
<div class="something">
important stuff
<div id="delete_me">
not so important stuff, better delete me
</div>
</div>
```

So that the result is solely

```
<div class="something">
important stuff
</div>
```

I can't be that difficult. I am going nuts every time I have to use DOMDocument.

This is such a simple question and an every day task and still I can't find a working solution.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Certain versions of `libxml` require a doctype to be present in order that `getElementById` will work correctly, hence the quite "hacky" approach here which tricks libxml slightly.

```
    $doc='<!doctype>';

    $html='
        <div class="something">
            important stuff
            <div id="delete_me">
                not so important stuff, better delete me
            </div>
        </div>';

    /* append the doctype */
    $html=$doc . $html;

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->validateOnParse = false;
    $dom->loadHTML( $html );

    /* get the element to be deleted */
    $div=$dom->getElementById('delete_me');

    /* delete the node */
    if( $div && $div->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ){
        $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
    }
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
    $dom=null;
```

Alternatively use `DOMXPath` to find the element by querying for the id and delete.

```
    $html='
        <div class="something">
            important stuff
            <div id="delete_me">
                not so important stuff, better delete me
            </div>
        </div>';
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->validateOnParse = false;
    $dom->loadHTML( $html );
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

    $col = $xp->query( '//div[ @id="delete_me" ]' );
    if( !empty( $col ) ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );
        }
    }
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
    $dom=null;
```